# Can h:commandLink be used with a single-click?

Tags: jsf, double-click, commandlink

I need an `h:commandLink` to send a value using `f:setPropertyActionListener` , like this:

```
<h:commandLink value="New Search" action="SearchAuthor"> 
         <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{searchAuthController.flag}" value="true" />
 </h:commandLink>
```

The `h:commandLink` needs a double click to make its action happen, but I'd like it to be used with a single click, is there any way to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: `h:commandLink` works fine on single click. Your problem is something else.

Comment: `h:commandLin` has `ondblclick` attribute. You can implement your logic there.

Comment: I'm sorry just said something wrong in the last comment(deleted it): the problem is: when I use h:commandLink it only works if I double click it, but I'd like it to work with a single-click.

Comment: Read my first comment.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it must be something else, will delete that question, thank you!